# Magento - update product image paths on multiple products through a csv file

Tags: magento, csv, import

I am trying to add products by duplicating them in a CSV file. It seems to work fine but when I update the product image path with the same path to multiple products it doesn't seem to update. When I export again and look at the data it has reverted to it original state. What is the problem here...?

Answer (score 1):

Please review the following: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/importing-product-images

Typical Problems:

Path

Name of File (Name does not match file name. ie: Name.jpg vs /name.jpg)

Image file does not exist on server for processing. (file is not at store/media/upload/file.jpg)

Permissions (store/media/* store/media/upload not accessible)

Reminder: When dealing with Image Modification/Upload etc, please flush (disable during trouble shooting) the cache, then re-enable after.

Uploading via Dataflow:
Assuming you have the correct basic required fields, there are two main behaviors.

If the SKU is unique, the product ID will be created in the system.
If the SKU exists, information will be replaced/updated or Appended in the system.

When you copy and paste, you will want to make sure each SKU is unique, and that there will be a correlating image that will 'live' on the server during the upload dataflow process.

In the case of Images, the Path is going to be looking for yourstoreroot/media/import/ for the images you reference in your image / small / thumbnail, if the image doesn't exist with the path described, or doesn't match exactly the name, then the data will not be added/appended in the cart as it is invalid to the import files and would not show on new exports.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I learned how to create an attribute, an attribute set, then a configurable product. With the configurable product I can apply the image once. Each product listing with a different size or color is listed as an associated product with all duplicate content but is not visible individually.

Here is a tutorial that got me started:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

Comment: Great to hear. Yes, configurable products cover similar groupings of items that you can then 'drive' down through with eg. Drop Down's as filters to reach a unique product sku, the Configurable Super Product become's a Facade hiding the individual simple products.

Some side effects will be: how many sku's you now have.
ex. New Configurable Style'd T-Shirt: (SKU: 123) 
Large Black Shirt (SKU: 123-LBS)
Medium Black Shirt (SKU: 123-MBS)
Normal Black Shirt (SKU: 123-NBS)
Small Black Shirt (SKU: 123-SBS)
Large White Shirt (SKU: 123-LWS)
Instead of many of the same products shown, you have the 1.

Answer (score 0):

Found this question via Google looking for something similar and thought I'd chime in.

The most common problem I've encountered (and its poorly documented) is that when importing using the built-in import tool, the "image" path must be relative to /media/import/. Note that by default there is no 'import' folder in /media, you'll need to make it.

That means that in your CSV under the "images" column, you should have '/somepicture.jpg', this corresponds to /media/import/somepicture.jpg during the actual import. If this is incorrect, while the import is going on you'll see a bunch of "image not found" errors scroll by, and the existing image data will not be updated.

Unfortunately it does not look like there is a way to simply update the stored image path (such as pointing a bunch of products to the same image) using the built-in importer, as it expects to be importing new images, and will dupe them up just like editing images manually does.